Does Acts 20:28 say that the church was purchased with the blood of God or the blood of the Lord?
Acts 20:28 in most translations read,

Keep watch over yourselves and the entire flock of which the Holy
Spirit has made you overseers. Be shepherds of the church of God,
which He purchased with His own blood.

However, variants in Greek actually render it "the church of the Lord", which would imply that the church was bought with the blood of the Lord instead of the blood of God.
In every other place throughout scripture, we read that the church was bought with the blood of the Son, the Christ, the Lord.
Is it the church of God, or church of the Lord?
Which variant is the original?

According to Greek Scholar A. T. Robertson it's the "Church of God." The church of God (την εκκλησιαν του θεου). The correct text, not "the church of the Lord" or "the church of the Lord and God" (Robertson, Introduction to Textual Criticism of the N.T., p. 189). Does  that answer your question to your satisfaction?

@Mr.Bond – perhaps it does, but I need you to explain why there is such a majority of texts reading "church of the Lord".

I looked it up and the majority say, "the Church of God." See here: https://www.bibleref.com/Acts/20/Acts-20-28.html Can you provide any and all translations that say, "church of the Lord?" The balls in your court now.

See also https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/98793/the-byzantine-majority-text-and-the-referent-of-acts-2028

This question is similar to: The Byzantine Majority Text and the referent of Acts 20:28. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is true that the Greek manuscripts at Acts 20:28 contain three different texts as follows (as listed in UBS5):

τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ Θεοῦ  (= "the Chruch of the God") as found in MSS 01(IV), 03(IV), 614, 1175, 1409, l60, l592, l598, l603, l1021, l1439, itala(various), vulgate, syriac, coptic, georgian, Athanasias, Basil, Epipanius, Chrysostom, Cyril, Ambrose.  This text used by UBS5, NA28, NA04, W&H, SBL, NIVGNT, TR, etc.
τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ κυρίου (= "the church of the Lord") as found in MSS P74(VII), A02(V), C04(V), D05(V), E08(VI), 044, 33, 36, 181, 307, 453, 610, 945, 1678, 1739, 1891, 2344, 2464, l599 itala(various), syriac, coptic, armenian, Irenaeus, Didymus, Theodoret, Jerome, Pelagius.  This text used by THGNT.
τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ κυρίου καὶ θεοῦ  (= "the church of the Lord and God") as found in MSS C04(3rd correction), L020(IX), P025(IX), slavic lectionary.  This text adopted by R+P Byzantine text, F35, OC-1904, Majority text.

For more details, see UBS5.  The current evidence is that the first of these readings is earliest.
In his Textual Commentary on the GNT, Bruce Metzger records the following:

The external evidence is singularly balanced between "church of God"
and "church of the Lord" (the reading "church of the Lord and God"
is obviously conflate, and therefore secondary - as are also the other
variant readings). Palaeographically, the difference concerns a single
letter: θ vs Κ.  In deciding between these two readings one must take
into account internal probabilities.
The expression εκκλησιαν κυριου occurs seven times in the Septuagint
but nowhere in the NT.  On the other hand, ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ Θεοῦ  appears
with moderate frequency (eleven times) in the epistles traditionally
ascribed to Paul, but nowhere else in the NT. (The phrase ἐκκλησίαι
πᾶσαι τοῦ Χριστοῦ  occurs once in Rom 16:16.) It is possible,
therefore, that a scribe, finding Θεοῦ  in his exemplar, was
influenced by OT passages and altered it to κυρίου.  On the other
hand, it is also possible that a scribe, influenced by Pauline usage,
changed κυρίου of his exemplar to Θεοῦ .
In support of the originality of κυρίου is the agreement (urged by a
number of scholars) that copyists were likely to substitute the more
common phrase τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ Θεοῦ  for the more rare phrase τὴν
ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ κυρίου.
On the other hand it is undeniable that Θεοῦ  is the more difficult
reading.  The following clause speaks of the church "which he obtained
διὰ τοῦ αἵματος τοῦ ἰδίου."  If this is taken in its usual sense
("with His own blood"), a copyist might well raise the question, Does
God have blood?, and thus be led to change Θεοῦ  to Κυρίου.  If
however, Κυρίου were the original reading, there is nothing unusual in
the phrase to catch the mind of the scribe and throw it off its
balance.  This and other considerations led the committee (as well as
a number of other scholars) to regard Θεοῦ  as the original reading.
... the Committee judged that θεοῦ is more likely to have been
altered to κυρίου than vice versa.

Lastly, the pivotal phrase "His own blood" or a slight variant always refers to that of the individual and never that of a family member.  For example:

Col 1:14 (NKJV) - in whom we have redemption through His blood, the forgiveness of sins.
Heb 9:12 - He did not enter by the blood of goats and calves, but He entered the Most Holy Place once for all by His own blood, thus securing eternal redemption.
Heb 13;12 - And so Jesus also suffered outside the city gate, to sanctify the people by His own blood.
Rev 1:5 - and from Jesus Christ, the faithful witness, the firstborn from the dead, and the ruler of the kings of the earth. To Him who loves us and has released us from our sins by His blood,
Rev 5:9 - And they sang a new song: “Worthy are You to take the scroll and open its seals, because You were slain, and by Your blood You purchased for God those from every tribe and tongue and people and nation.

The same is true in the OT: Isa 49:26, Prov 1:18, 2 Sam 1:16, Gen 9:6, Eze 16:6, etc.  This tends to confirm that "His own blood" is that of Jesus in Act 20:28.  1 Tim 3:16 lends further weight to this.

@RussellMcMahon - see also https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/92940/did-jesus-want-john-to-reference-isaiah-354-6-and-recognize-the-miracles-as-pr/92944?noredirect=1#comment206043_92944

You might find a place to put that link in your answer.

I just removed almost 20 comments that had gotten theological. Let's all try to keep it to interpretation process and leave theology for Christianity.SE.

@Jesse why remove comments without without even a link to the discussion/conversation?

@Austin you raise a wonderful question. I left a comment, then deleted it so moderators could refer to it. The system, for some reason, would not move the comments to chat. They had to be removed because they got theological, so leaving them was not a viable alternative. It was a bug.

@Jesse, undestandable. Thanks.

Here's Acts 20:28 from the Codex Sinaiticus translated using ChatGPT, not the Codex Webite(I do not trust their translation):

προϲεχετε εαυτοιϲ και παντι τω ποι μνιω εν ω ϋμαϲ το πνα το αγιον εθε
το επιϲκοπουϲ ποι μενιν την εκκλη ϲιαν του θυ ην πε ριεποιηϲατο δια
του αιματοϲ του ϊδιου
"Take heed to yourselves and to all the flock, among which the Holy
Spirit has made you overseers, to shepherd the church of God, which He
purchased with His own blood."

Acts 20:28 - Codex Sinaiticus
Looks like "Theos"(God/Elohim) is used in the earliest versions. I see "Theos" replaced in the Tischendorf 8th Edition only... I see "κύριος" before "Theos" in the Greek Orthodox Church 1904 and RP Byzantine Majority Text 2005.
Acts 20:28 - Greek Texts
I believe "kurios"/"Lord" should not be there.

Bruce Metzger has an extensive explanation in his textual commentary that is difficult to summarize.  So, I have quoted it below and also included somewhat of a summary that you will find lacking without the quote.  1) When Byzantine texts encountered variations, they usually included both “church of the Lord and God” 2) Copyist changes usually go from difficult readings to clearer reading, not the reverse. 3) There was probably some understanding of the reader for "his own blood" to be a abbreviation of "his own son's blood."

20:28      θεοῦ {C}


The external evidence is singularly balanced between “church of God” and “church of the Lord” (the reading “church of the Lord and God” is obviously conflate, and therefore secondary—as are also the other variant readings). Palaeographically the difference concerns only a single letter: ΘΥ and ΚΥ. In deciding between the two readings one must take into account internal probabilities.


The expression ἐκκλησία κυρίου occurs seven times in the Septuagint but nowhere in the New Testament. On the other hand, ἐκκλησία τοῦ θεοῦ appears with moderate frequency (eleven times) in the Epistles traditionally ascribed to Paul, but nowhere else in the New Testament. (The phrase αἱ ἐκκλησίαι πᾶσαι τοῦ Χριστοῦ occurs once in Ro 16:16.) It is possible, therefore, that a scribe, finding θεοῦ in his exemplar, was influenced by Old Testament passages and altered it to κυρίου. On the other hand, it is also possible that a scribe, influenced by Pauline usage, changed κυρίου of his exemplar to θεοῦ.


In support of the originality of κυρίου is the argument (urged by a number of scholars) that copyists were likely to substitute the more common phrase ἡ ἐκκλησία τοῦ θεοῦ for the more rare phrase ἡ ἐκκλησία τοῦ κυρίου.


On the other hand, it is undeniable that θεοῦ is the more difficult reading. The following clause speaks of the church “which he obtained διὰ τοῦ αἴματος τοῦ ἰδίου.” If this is taken in its usual sense (“with his own blood”), a copyist might well raise the question, Does God have blood?, and thus be led to change θεοῦ to κυρίου. If, however, κυρίου were the original reading, there is nothing unusual in the phrase to catch the mind of the scribe and throw it off its balance. This and other considerations led the Committee (as well as a variety of other scholars) to regard θεοῦ as the original reading.


Instead of the usual meaning of διὰ τοῦ αἵματος τοῦ ἰδίου, it is possible that the writer of Acts intended his readers to understand the expression to mean “with the blood of his Own.” (It is not necessary to suppose, with Hort, that υἱοῦ may have dropped out after τοῦ ἰδίου, though palaeographically such an omission would have been easy.) This absolute use of ὁ ἴδιος is found in Greek papyri as a term of endearment referring to near relatives. It is possible, therefore, that “his Own” (ὁ ἴδιος) was a title that early Christians gave to Jesus, comparable to “the Beloved” (ὁ ἀγαπητός); compare Ro 8:32, where Paul refers to God “who did not spare τοῦ ἰδίου υἱοῦ” in a context that clearly alludes to Gn 22:16, where the Septuagint has ἀγαπητοῦ υἱοῦ.


Without committing itself concerning what some have thought to be a slight probability that τοῦ ἰδίου is used here as the equivalent of τοῦ ἰδίου υἱοῦ, the Committee judged that the reading θεοῦ was more likely to have been altered to κυρίου than vice versa.
--
Metzger, B. M., United Bible Societies. (1994). A textual commentary on the Greek New Testament, second edition a companion volume to the United Bible Societies’ Greek New Testament (4th rev. ed.) (pp. 425–427). United Bible Societies.


+1 So the phrase "his own blood" should be taken to mean that God purchased the church with the blood of his own son?

@OneGodOneLord The quoted text does not say that. It says that " there is a slight probability that ..."

Acts 20:28

προσέχετε ἑαυτοῖς καὶ παντὶ τῷ ποιμνίῳ, ἐν ᾧ ὑμᾶς τὸ πνεῦμα τὸ ἅγιον ἔθετο ἐπισκόπους, ποιμαίνειν τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ θεοῦ, ἣν περιεποιήσατο διὰ τοῦ αἵματος τοῦ ἰδίου

If we examine the last bit, ἣν περιεποιήσατο διὰ τοῦ αἵματος τοῦ ἰδίου the antecedent of the relative pronoun ἣν is the church, and it is feminine. There is no relative pronoun referring back to God in this clause.
"He" comes from the conjugation of the verb περιεποιήσατο and from the context we all know that "he" = Jesus Christ. There doesn't appear to be any grammatical justification for conflating "he" with God from the previous clause here.
The books of Acts always asserts that Jesus is the one that died on the cross, and distinguishes him from God. For instance:
Acts 2:36

Therefore let all the house of Israel know for certain that God has made Him both Lord and Christ — this Jesus whom you crucified

Acts 3:13

The God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, the God of our fathers, has glorified His servant Jesus, the one whom you handed over and disowned in the presence of Pilate, when he had decided to release Him.

Acts 4:10

let it be known to all of you and to all the people of Israel, that by the name of Jesus Christ the Nazarene, whom you crucified, whom God raised from the dead—by this name this man stands here before you in good health.

Acts 5:30

The God of our fathers raised up Jesus, whom you put to death by hanging Him on a cross.

Acts 7:55

But he, being full of the Holy Spirit, looked intently into heaven and saw the glory of God, and Jesus standing at the right hand of God;

To conclude, who "he" is must be determined by the context of the verse. There is no relative pronoun in the clause whose antecedent is God. And everyone recognizes that in this context "he" = Jesus Christ. There is no grammatical reason to conflate him with God in this sentence - and within the context of the book of Acts such an idea is contrary to the Christology presented.
In Acts, Christ is the suffering servant of God who died on the cross and subsequently ascended to God's right hand. He is distinct from and subordinate to God.
Attempting to use the somewhat ambiguous nature of the verse to attempt to plugin the Trinity within the context of a book whose Christology does not agree with it is disingenuous.

Own is in reference to “he” = Jesus, the subject of the verb.

@Correct - that is the point!

@Dottard if you recognize that it is Jesus’ own blood then what’s your point?

My opening statement was concerning ἣν being a feminine relative pronoun - is that what you are saying is incorrect???

I was refering to your claim that no pronoun refers to God.

ἰδίου isn’t a relative pronoun, it is an adjective. And it references the one doing the action - not God back in the previous clause.

And, actually, ἰδίου is genitive so the literal translation would be “of his own.” So if we did take “he” to be “God” then “of his own” could idiomatically be referencing his Son.

The word is a genitive adjective, singular, and thus modifies a noun, in this case, the blood that belongs to Jesus.

It’s a (non-substantival) adjective and therefore modifies a noun - that it is genitive specifies how it modifies that noun.

@RyanPierceWilliams, the "he" is God, who purchased the church with the blood of his own [Beloved Son].

@OneGodOneLord I would support that interpretation of the verse. The verse is a bit ambiguous, which is why different versions translate this so differently. But so long as the translation is inline with the rest of Acts then I’d say it’s a valid one to consider

The specific order of "the blood of his own" in Greek lends full support to God (the Father) purchasing the church with the blood of his own (Son). Greek always puts the possessive after the possessor.

Answer
John 20:28 - Scripture calls Jesus as both God and Lord.
Acts 20:28 - It doesn’t make any difference whether it is the church of God or church of Lord. The meaning is the same.
So, “my God and my Lord” purchased the Church with His own blood.
Explanation
Those unitarians who do not have any problem with the “Church of God”, will have to insist that it should be “the blood of His own [Son]” as we can see in the New World Translation of the Jehovah’s Witnesses (the word “Son” is not in the Greek MSS).
However, the unitarians who insist on the “Church of Lord” cannot translate this as the above because the Lord has no son!
So, they have to translate as “His own blood”.
Thus, if it is “church of God”, then it will be “the blood of His own”.
If it is “church of Lord”, then it has to be “His own blood”.
This will prove that it is the theology that determines the translation instead of the other way around.
So which one is the correct translation?
In fact, the NT Greek provides both for the same meaning.
A)  His own blood
The Greek for this structure is “tou idiou haimatos” (“of the own blood”) as we see in Hebrews 9:12 and 13:12.
Here, the structure is “article + adjective + noun”
We have a similar construction in the case of the Holy Spirit.
“to Hagion Pneuma” = “the Holy Spirit” (Luke 12:10, 12 and 1 John
5:7).
Other similar constructions are:
“ton hagion paida” or “the holy child” (Acts 4:27).
“ton hagion topon” or “the holy place” (Acts 21:28).
B)  The Blood of The Own
Here, the structure is “article + noun + (same) article + adjective” but the meaning is the same as we will see below:
“tou haimatos tou idiou” or “the blood (of) the own” which means “one’s own blood” (Acts 20:28 in Genitive case).
We have a similar construction in the case of the Holy Spirit in the very same verse:
“to Pneuma to Hagion” or “the Spirit the Holy”  which simply means “the Holy Spirit” (Acts 20:28 in Nominative case).
Now let us look at the Holy Spirit in the Genitive case:
“tou Pneumatos tou Hagiou” or “the Spirit (of) the Holy” which simply means “of the Holy Spirit” (Mat 12:32; Luke 2:26; Heb 9:8 in Genitive case).
The New World Translation (NWT) of Jehovah’s Witnesses translates this verse thus: “the holy spirit”.
What is significant is that they do not translate it as “the spirit of the holy [One]”!
Another two examples:

“tein doxan tein idian” or “the glory the own” which means “own glory” (John 7:18 in Accusative case).

The NWT gives it thus: “his own glory”. They do not translate it as “the glory to his own [one]”.

“(en) to onomati to idio” or “(in) the name the own” which means “(in) his own name” (John 5:43 in Dative case).

The NWT gives it thus” “in his own name”. They do not translate it as “in the name of his own [one]”.
So we see that though word order can be different in Greek, the meaning is the same. Now look at this:
Contrast These
We again look at Acts 21:28: (article + adjective + noun)
“ton hagion topon (touton)” or “the holy place (this)” which means this holy place.
The NWT writes: “this holy place”.
Now look at Acts 1:25: (_article + noun + same article + adjective)
“(eis) ton topon ton idion” or “(to) the place the own” which means “to his own place”.
The NWT writes: “to his own place” and not as ‘to the place of his own [one]’.
The decisive example:
“He first found his own brother Simon” (John 1:41; NWT).
Here, the Greek has the construction: “ton adelphon ton idion Simona” or “the brother the own Simon”.
No one would say that Andrew found ‘the brother of his own Simon’!!
Verse 40 says that Andrew is the brother of Simon Peter. So when Andrew found the brother of his own Simon, who would that be?
Andrew himself!!
So, did Andrew find himself and talk to himself?
No, that would be a crazy sense.
Thus we see that “ton idion adelphon” and “ton adelphon ton idion” both mean the same: “the own brother”.
In other words, “article + adjective + noun” and “article + noun + (same) article + adjective” both mean the same.
Conclusion
So, we have seen that:
If “tou pneumatos tou hagiou” is “the holy spirit” (NWT);
If “tein doxan tein idian” is “his own glory” (NWT);
If “to onomati to idio” is “his own name” (NWT);
If “ton topon ton idion” is “his own place” (NWT);
If “ton adelphon ton idion” is “his own brother” (NWT);
Then, definitely, “tou haimatos tou idiou” (Acts 20:28) is “His own blood”.

Sorry. You have no construction of article + genitive + ton idion. Or simply genitive + ton idion. None of the cases are decisive in impact on the translation of Acts 20:28. Nice attempt to pull a fast one. Besides most translation committees acknowledge the meaning is ambiguous which means context would determine the meaning. This is why the meaning can be different of it is either the church of the Lord or the church of God. Even in English, the phrase "blood of his own is ambiguous." Let's not artificially declare what is decisive what is not decisive.

I didn’t get what you meant by “article + genitive + ton idion. Or simply genitive + ton idion”. Would you explain? I am open to learning. My point is: whose blood it is should be decided by the grammar of the sentence; not by whether it is church of “God” or “Lord”. Then the ambiguity will disappear. The same structure, i.e., “article + noun + same article + adjective” in other parts of the Scripture does not provide any ambiguity; only in Acts 20:28 that is given ambiguity. This is theological determinism that is to be avoided.

Oops. Should have said  “article + genitive + tou idiou. Or simply genitive + tou idiou”. The point is that you don't have one example with tou idiou genitive construction following another genitive as in Acts 20:28. Double genitive word order may be important. Examples lacking "idiou" are irrelevant since the word "idiou" is the source of the ambiguity. Regardless of double genitive word order importance, multiple translation committees, including ESV & NET, in their notes, indicate meaning is not determined by grammar alone. Each option is equally likely requiring context/theology to decide.

You said, “Double genitive word order may be important.” Yes, the word order is important. I gave you “tou Pneumatos tou Hagiou” (Mat 12:32; Luke 2:26; Heb 9:8) which is in the double Genitive case and means “the Spirit of the Holy”. This is translated as “the Holy Spirit”. Even NWT translates it as “the holy spirit”. What is significant is that they don’t translate it as “the spirit of his holy [one]”. There is no ambiguity in this double genitive case.

So, “tou pneumatos tou hagiou” is similar to “tou haimatos tou idiou” and has the same double genitive structure (article + noun + same article + adjective) as you said. If “tou pneumatos tou hagiou” = “the spirit of the holy” = “the holy spirit”, then “tou haimatos tou idiou” = the blood of the own” = “the own blood”, i.e., his own blood.

It can't just be a double genetive, but it needs to be a double genitive with ἴδιος. The established source of the ambiguity is primarily with ἴδιος and not with the sentence structure itself. There are several passages where ἴδιος by itself cleary refers to other people in Acts 4:23, Acts 24:23, and  John 1:11 and several other examples where it applies to either people or other possessions.

+1 "This will prove that it is the theology that determines the translation instead of the other way around." Indeed! This is even worse than what I call biazogesis. Revising the holy scriptures to suit one's theology exposes flagrant contempt for the Word of God.  A scribe was rebuked in the margin notes of Hebrews 1:3 in Codex Vaticanus for exactly that! You can read about it here: https://taylormarshall.com/2018/04/hebrews-13-manuscript-changes-rebuke.html
